# Group text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, group-by

I have a table with 3 columns,

[image]

I want to group the Text rows to something like this :

[image]

Please help

Comment: i was trying to do in excel and not VBA

Comment: Do you have a version of Excel with the FILTER() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel365 then it would be easier to achieve your result. As per below screenshot put following formula to `G2` cell.

```
=UNIQUE(C2:C5)
```

Then put below formula to `E2` cell.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($C$2:$C$5=$G2,A$2:A$5,""))
```

[image]

Comment: To complete it, you could e.g. add an `INDEX/MATCH` formula for cell `F2`.

Comment: Or just use `=UNIQUE(B2:C5)` in cell F2.

Comment: How can i do this dynamically without inserting cell numbers as there may be a long list with hundreds of records

Comment: @Sam Then use full column as reference like `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C2:C5=G2,A:A,""))
`